# Getting Error import-module : Process should have elevated status to access IIS configuration data

Tags: .net, iis, github-actions, .net-4.8

`name: DEEEEDeploy to Development Environment
on:
push:
branches:
- master
pull_request:
branches:
- PrepRod
env:

AZURE_DEVWEBAPP_NAME: GitAc-Dev
AZURE_PREPRODWEBAPP_NAME: GitAc-PreProd
AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: 'D:\a\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\bin'
jobs:
Build:
runs-on: windows-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
- name: Setup MSBuild
  uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1

- name: Setup NuGet
  uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

- name: Restore NuGet packages
  run: nuget restore GitNewTest2/GitNewTest2.sln

- name: build
  run: |
       msbuild GitNewTest2/GitNewTest2.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /verbosity:minimal
- name: publish
  run: |
       msbuild GitNewTest2/GitNewTest2.sln /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:PublishDir="./artifacts"
```

- name: Upload artifacts
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
  with:
  name: myapp
  path: ${{env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH}}

  - name: running1
    run: |
    Get-location
  - name: running6
    run: |
    dir D:\a\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\bin
- name: Download artifacts
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
  with:
  name: myapp
  path: 'C:\app.publish'

  - name: running
    run: |
    Get-location
  - name: running2
    run: |
    dir
  - name: running3
    run: |
    cd C:\app.publish
    dir

  DeployDev:

  ```
   name: Dev
   needs: Build
    # if: github.event_name == 'refs/heads/master'
   runs-on: self-hosted
   env:
      DEV_WEBSITE_NAME: ${{secrets.DEV_WEBSITE_NAME}}
      DEV_APP_POOL_NAME: ${{secrets.DEV_APP_POOL_NAME}}
      WEBAPP_MSDeploy_USERNAME: ${{secrets.IIS_USERNAME}}
      WEBAPP_MSDeploy_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.IIS_PASSWORD}}
   environment:
        name: Dev
   steps:
      - name: Checkout Code 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Download artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
         name: myapp
         path: 'C:\app.publish'


      - name: copying
        run: |
             $path="${{github.workspace}}\GitNewTest2\Scripts\DevTestScript.ps1"
             echo $path
             & $path

             cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\
             dir
             Copy-Item C:\app.publish\* C:\inetpub\wwwroot\${{env.DEV_WEBSITE_NAME}} -Recurse -Force
  ```
- name: create new apppool
  run: |

  ```
            Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-File C:\actions-runner\_work\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\Scripts\DevTestAppPool.ps1"

            # & C:\actions-runner\_work\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\Scripts\DevTestAppPool.ps1
     - name: create website
       run: |
          & C:\actions-runner\_work\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\GitNewTest2\Scripts\DevTestWebsite.ps1
     - name: config to use new appool
       run: |
         Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\Sites\${{env.DEV_WEBSITE_NAME}}" -Name "applicationPool" -Value ${{env.DEV_APP_POOL_NAME}}


     - name: Deploy to IIS
       run: |
          start-process PowerShell -verb runas 
          iisreset /stop
          iisreset /start
  ```

`

Above I shared my github workflow code , I have tried with command RunAs , then tried editing registry policy as well. Stil I see the same error . Any help would be greate.

Comment: For troubleshooting this issue, have you read this article, it might help you: https://blogs.iis.net/ma_khan/troubleshooting-iis-powershell-module-on-windows-7-rc

Answer (score 0):

I am using self hosted GitHub action and this happens to me:

I was struggling with this as I have this error when I am trying to make the pool sleep and then start it and the privilege causes it

```
Run Stop-WebAppPool -Name "DotNetTesting"
Process should have elevated status to access IIS configuration data.
stop-webitem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.
```

**I solved it by going to the action runner and trying to run "run.cmd" as an administrator and solved.**